# Duplicate labels and points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help with ggplot's legend labels. As mark in the image below, there appear to be two labels (points) in the legend labels. Additionally, I see a few extra dots in the actual plots too. I have no idea what these stand for. How do I get rid of the duplicate points and extra dots in the legend label?
I would value any assistance.
also how can i add asterics to estimate which are significant?
[image]

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(sjlabelled)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(pscl)
library(boot)

library(broom)
library(poissonreg)
library(tidyverse) ## purrr::map_dfr, ggplot ...
theme_set(theme_bw())
library(colorspace)



zinb_all_uni <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age,
                         link="logit",
                         dist = "negbin",
                         data=caterpillor)



summary(zinb_all_uni)
exp(coef(zinb_all_uni)) 

exp(coef(Zinb_uni_sub))

plot_model(zinb_all_uni, type="est")



zinb_full_adj <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                          link="logit",
                          dist = "negbin",
                          data=caterpillor)

summary(zinb_full_adj)
exp(coef(zinb_full_adj)) 
plot_model(zinb_full_adj, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))

############ second model#######


Zinb_uni_sub <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age,
                         link="logit",
                         dist = "negbin",
                         data=subset(caterpillor, country=="eng"))



summary(Zinb_uni_sub)
exp(coef(Zinb_uni_sub)) 

plot_model(Zinb_uni_sub, type="est")



zinb_adj_sub <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                         link="logit",
                         dist = "negbin",
                         data=subset(caterpillor, country=="eng"))

summary(zinb_adj_sub)
exp(coef(zinb_adj_sub)) 

plot_model(zinb_adj_sub, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))



mod_list <- list(all_adj = zinb_full_adj, adj_sub = zinb_adj_sub)


tidy(zinb_all_uni, type = "all")

coefs <- (mod_list
          |> map_dfr(tidy, type = "all",
                     .id = "model")
          ## construct CIs
          |> mutate(conf.low  = qnorm(0.025, estimate, std.error),
                    conf.high = qnorm(0.975, estimate, std.error))
          |> filter(term != "(Intercept)")  ## usually don't want this
          ## cosmetic (strip results down to the components we actually need)
          |> dplyr::select(model, term, type, estimate, conf.low, conf.high)
          ## back-transform
          |> mutate(across(c(estimate, conf.low, conf.high), exp))
          |> filter(stringr::str_detect(term, "^age"))
)

ggplot(coefs, aes(x = estimate, y = term, colour = str_wrap(model, width = 5))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 1, color = "yellow", size = 1)+
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high),
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
                  size=0.4) +
  ## separate count-ratio and odds-ratio (conditional/zero) plots
  facet_wrap(~type, scale = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(x=estimate,label=sprintf("%0.2f", estimate)), position = position_dodge(0.5),vjust=-0.5,size=3.5)+
  #scale_color_discrete_qualitative()+ 
  labs(x = "gy", y= "age")+
  scale_color_manual(name="Model",labels=c("Fullfasdfas\ndfadasdk\nljaflsdjfalsfasdf", "Subadfa sdfa\nasdfas dfasd fsdf asdfasf"), values=c("dodgerblue4", "firebrick4"))+geom_point(size=0.5)
  
  


#####  data 

caterpillor=structure(list(id = 1:100,
                           age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                           .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
                           sex = structure(c(2L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L),
                                           .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"),
                           country = structure(c(1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                               .Label = c("eng", "scot", "wale"), class = "factor"), 
                           edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                           .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"),
                           lungfunction = c(45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                            50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                            50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 
                                            90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L),
                           ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
                                      8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
                                      9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
                           no2_quintile = structure(c(1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                      5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
                                                    .Label = c("q1", "q2", 
                                                               "q3", "q4", "q5"), class = "factor")),
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                          -100L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your legend is that the `geom_text` layer is reflected in the legend key too via a letter `"a"`. To prevent that add `show.legend=FALSE` to `geom_text`. The issue with the duplicated points is that besides the dodged `geom_pointrange` you had a second and unddodged `geom_point`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

ggplot(coefs, aes(x = estimate, y = term, colour = str_wrap(model, width = 5))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 1, color = "yellow", size = 1) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
    size = 0.4
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~type, scale = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(x = estimate, label = sprintf("%0.2f", estimate)),
    position = position_dodge(0.5), vjust = -0.5, size = 3.5, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(x = "gy", y = "age") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Model",
    labels = c(
      "Fullfasdfas\ndfadasdk\nljaflsdjfalsfasdf",
      "Subadfa sdfa\nasdfas dfasd fsdf asdfasf"
    ),
    values = c("dodgerblue4", "firebrick4")
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Just as an example to indicate the significance via an asterisk you could add a column to your `coefs` dataset with an asterisk for significant values and an empty string for non-significant ones. This could then be "added" to the text label inside `geom_text`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

set.seed(123)
coefs$is_signif <- sample(c("", "*"), 6, replace = TRUE)

ggplot(coefs, aes(x = estimate, y = term, colour = str_wrap(model, width = 5))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 1, color = "yellow", size = 1) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
    size = 0.4
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~type, scale = "free") +
  geom_text(aes(x = estimate, label = sprintf("%0.2f%s", estimate, is_signif)),
    position = position_dodge(0.5), vjust = -0.5, size = 3.5, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(x = "gy", y = "age") +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "Model",
    labels = c(
      "Fullfasdfas\ndfadasdk\nljaflsdjfalsfasdf",
      "Subadfa sdfa\nasdfas dfasd fsdf asdfasf"
    ),
    values = c("dodgerblue4", "firebrick4")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your prompt reply and for identifying the error source. is it possible to add asterisks next to values which is significant?

Comment: Sure. See my edit for the general approach.

Comment: @thanks Stefan, many thanks for your help. I removed the duplicate legend. but I am unable to add the asterisks to significant values in ggplot. i put ur code coefs$is_signif <- sample(c("", "*"), 6, replace = TRUE)  before the ggplot command.

Comment: Have you also used the adjusted geom_text, i.e. `label = sprintf("%0.2f%s", estimate, is_signif)?

Comment: many thanks for your prompt reply and advice. i adjusted geom_text for label = sprintf("%0.2f%s", estimate, is_signif) but no success. after adding this there is s after every estimate in ggplot.